# javascript addEventListner

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm working on RC RPi car and I'm trying to make web control. But I got stuck at begining I don't know why addEventListner isn't working. I tried to change element on which i add listner and only thing that seems to work is

```
<p id="demo">WATCH.</p>
```

please HELP

Thank you for any answers

FULL CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.box{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid orange;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: lightyellow;

}
</style>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);

function mouseDown() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The mouse button is held down.";
}

function mouseUp() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You released the mouse button.";
}
</script>
<p id="demo">WATCH.</p>
 <div class="box" id="box1">
<h3> FORW </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the `<script>` element to after the elements it tries to reference. (Does this code not give you an error in the browser's developer console?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the DOM is loaded after the script is executed.

there's 2 ways to fix this issue:

1. wrap your code in

   ```
   window.onload = function(){
     //your code here
   }
   ```

   2.put your script after the elemets